# Error 'Dependency failed' when mounting Azure Files with /etc/fstab, but manually it works

Tags: azure, azure-storage

In Azure, I created
- 2 file shares
- Ubuntu 18.04 VM

When I try to mount my file share via /etc/fstab, it doesn't work.
However `mount` command works fine.

Entry in the /etc/fstab:

> //audiocloud.file.core.windows.net/audiocloud /mnt/audiocloud cifs nofail,vers=3.0,credentials=/etc/smbcredentials/audiocloud.cred,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,serverino

The mount not created.

I tried to look in syslog:

`slavik@ub18:/mnt$ cat /var/log/syslog | grep mnt
Aug 30 07:10:16 ub18 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /mnt.
Aug 30 07:10:16 ub18 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /mnt/audiocloud.
Aug 30 07:10:16 ub18 systemd[1]: mnt-audiocloud.mount: Job mnt-audiocloud.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Aug 30 07:10:16 ub18 systemd[1]: mnt.mount: Job mnt.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.`

What does this error means?

Here is `mount` command, which works successfully:

> sudo mount -t cifs //audiocloud.file.core.windows.net/audiocloud /mnt/audiocloud -o vers=3.0,username=###,password=###,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,sec=ntlmssp

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the issue was caused by another mount in `/etc/fstab`, which added by Azure. Somehow I missed it:

> /dev/disk/cloud/azure_resource-part1    /mnt    auto    defaults,nofail,x-systemd.requires=cloud-init.service,comment=cloudconfig       0       2

Apparently, it mounts to `/mnt`, so my attempt to mount at `/mnt/audiocloud` failed.

Not sure though, why the `mount` command works for the same mount location...